# There is no error?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

There is no output error from eclipse. So I do not know why this program won't run.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends Gui {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        JFrame window = new JFrame("l");
        Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        window.setBackground(black);
         JDialog start = new JDialog(window, ";;");
         start.setBounds(500, 500, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: At least, for a first try, set the window visible : `window.setVisible(true);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues, the predominant being that you did not set a size, or make your window (or your dialog) visible -

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("l");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // <-- Handle closing 
                                           // the window.
    Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    window.setBackground(black);
    window.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); // <-- set a size.
    window.setVisible(true); // <-- set it visible.
    JDialog start = new JDialog(window, ";;");
    start.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300)); // <-- set a size.
    start.setVisible(true); // <-- set it visible.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to call at least `window.setVisible(true);` There are also other properties you should set (almost) everytime you open new JFrame like default close operation or size, check some basic [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for it.

Comment: You should also set window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); otherwise the program will just keep running in the background